# Sequlize association returns SequelizeInstance instead of object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequlizejs 2.0.0-rc4.

I have two entities: `Feeds` (containing an owner_id field) and `Owners`. Basically, there is a one-to-many relationship between `Feeds` and `Owners` - an `Owner` has many `Feeds`.

I have tried modelling this many different ways, but the only way I got it right is:

```
Owner.hasMany(Feed, {foreignKey: 'owner_id'});
Feed.belongsTo(Owner, {foreignKey: 'owner_id'});
```

The only problem with this is the fact that when I try to get a Feed like so:

```
models.feeds.findAll({
    include: [models.owners]
}).then(function (feeds) {
   // feeds will contain a SequlizeInstance object
});
```

Then the result will contain a `SequlizeInstance` object instead of a Owner object, which I then have to access through something like `feeds.owners.dataValues`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem here :). Sequelize returns sequelize instances because they are what allows you to do all the lovely sequelize stuff, such as `feed.owner.updateAttributes({.. })`.

If you want the plain values from the owner object, you should call [`get`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/instance/#getkey-options-objectany) or [`toJSON`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/instance/#tojson)